# PdfLaTex: Caption in Bold while Subcaption Not

Tags: pdftex, captions, subcaption

When I'm using the template from Elsevier, I want to make the caption of the figure in bold while the subfigure does not (for instance "(a), (b), (c)" as the labels instead of "**(a)**, **(b)**, **(c)**", while "**Fig.1** Opppps" as the caption), anyone knows that how can I realize it?

Below is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add

\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
 
\shorttitle{A}    
\shortauthors{A et al}  
\title [mode = title]{A}  

\begin{abstract}
B
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
\sep A
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

A \Cref{fig1}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
           \centering
           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{4mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{4mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Examples of images: (a) A, (b) B and (c) C.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

And the package is available here:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/

Thanks all in advance! Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[labelfont=normalfont]{subcaption}`

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!